# Creating batch file from ERDAS IMAGINE Spatial Modeler?

Tags: batch, erdas-imagine, model-maker, spatial-modeler

How to create batch file from the ERDAS IMAGINE Spatial Modeler?

I want to do the same process to different input images, something similar which we can do by batch processing of the existing programs in Erdas.

If there is no inbuilt function then one can use model maker to make *.gmd (graphical model) file but how to batch it?

Answer (score 0):

See the Hexagon link below:
[batch processing with model maker](https://supportsi.hexagon.com/s/article/Geodetic-Reprojection-of-Raster-Imagery?language=en_US)
It shows a way to get what's in the model into the standard batch window interface.